# Дизайн layer-list

Tags: android, xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#AAEEEEEE"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#AACCCCCC"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

В таком стиле оформлены элементы в ListView и выглядят вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь добавить второй прямоугольник для отрисовки вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но никак не получается корректно это сделать. Второй вариант получается при добавлении в конце layer-list

```
<item
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:width="60dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#AACCCCCC"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Но корректно это работает только в предпросмотре. Подскажите, как отредактировать, чтобы отображалось корректно?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Вы запускаете на устройстве < API 23, т.к. параметр `android:width` у `item` поддерживается начиная с API 23

Может Вам будет проще установить задний фон сразу у `TextView`, который отвечает за вывод надписи `PDF`

И еще один вопрос, почему Вы вручную создаете тень для карточки, а не воспользуетесь `CardView` от Google

Comment: Когда писал код 2 года назад, не знал про существование карточек, а теперь не хочется рефакторить много кода из-за этого.